# Possible ways of implementing a dynamic barrier in mulithreaded programs

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads

I read this in a paper...

> Consequently, our tool only checkpoints a thread when it is executing
>   at a known safe point: kernel entry, kernel exit, or certain
>   interruptible sleeps in the kernel that we have determined to be safe.
>   **The thread that initiates a multithreaded fork creates a barrier on
>   which it waits until all other threads reach a safe point. Once all
>   threads reach the barrier, the original thread creates the checkpoint,
>   then lets the other threads continue execution.**

Now my question is, can anyone guess what kind of barrier the authors are talking about. How a thread creates a barrier and inserts the barrier dynamically in other threads as well? Any working example will be highly appreciated.

**EDITED**

Please don't say use **pthread_barrier_wait**, because that is not the question. Here apparently the authors have a thread that inserts barriers into other threads dynamically. I want to know how?

Comment: Why not ask the authors, instead of guessing?

Comment: "apparently the ... thread inserts barriers into other threads dynamically". The paragraph does not say this, you are inferring it. Ask the authors. Odds are that they are indeed using simple `pthread_barrier_wait`. Occam's razor applies here.

Comment: Surely this is a kernelspace implementation of checkpoint/restart? Is the paper freely available? Maybe the implementation has hooked into those "safe points", doing the barrier dance when there is a checkpoint in progress.

Comment: Can you give more information about the paper you're quoting so we can get more context? That way we might not have to guess. A link would be ideal.

Comment: Yes Michael, the paper's link is this... www.eecs.umich.edu/~nsatish/papers/ASPLOS-10-Respec.pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The paper you're asking about appears to be ["Respec: Efficient Online Multiprocessor Replay via Speculation and External Determinism"](http://www.eecs.umich.edu/~nsatish/papers/ASPLOS-10-Respec.pdf). The paper mentions:

> We modified the Linux kernel to implement our techniques.

and

> We therefore created a new Linux primitive, called a multithreaded fork, that creates a child process with the same number of threads as its parent.

So when the paper says that

> Respec only checkpoints a thread when it is executing at a known safe point: kernel entry, kernel exit, or certain interruptible sleeps in the kernel that we have determined to be safe. The thread that initiates a multithreaded fork creates a barrier on which it waits until all other threads reach a safe point. Once all threads reach the barrier, the original thread creates the checkpoint, then lets the other threads continue execution.

I'd assume that among the modifications they made to the Linux kernel was logic that threads in the process being logged will 'enter' the barrier when they reach one of those "safe points" (I'd also assume only if there's been a 'multithreaded fork' issued to create the barrier). Since this is occurring in the kernel, it would be easy enough to implement a barrier - there's not really anything dynamic going on. The modified kernel has the barriers implemented at those strategic safe points.

I haven't really read the paper (just skimmed a few bits). It's not entirely clear to me what might happen if one or more threads is performing work that doesn't require entering the kernel for a long period of time - it appears that the system depends on the threads getting to those explicit safe points. So threads shouldn't dawdle in a CPU intensive loop for too long (which is probably not an issue for the vast majority of programs):

> Note that the actual execution time of an epoch may be longer than the epoch interval due to our barrier implementation; a checkpoint cannot be taken until all threads reach the barrier.

Comment: Surely context switches due to quanta expiration count as kernel entry, the only unsafe points would be long-running computations in kernel mode, uninterruptible sleeps and some kinds of interruptible sleeps.

Comment: @ninjali: I don't know enough about the system the paper describes to say for sure, but I'd assume that a context switch due to quanta expiration is probably *not* a safe time to checkpoint a thread.

Comment: Why not? Pure userspace computations shouldn't be an unsafe place to checkpoint a thread, I think the only problematic places would be while running in kernelspace.

Comment: @ninjali: You might well be right. I'd certainly have to do more study/analysis than the little I've done so far to prove what you say is wrong (if it even is wrong). I'm not really in a position to defend my comment - it's more an uneasy feeling than an assertion... On the other hand, if I were implementing this checkpointing tool, I'd have to do more analysis to feel comfortable with depending on what you're saying. But it certainly might just be a matter of eliminating ignorance on my part.

Answer (score 2):

Well considering that your question is tagged with linux and pthreads, I can only imagine that it's referring to pthread barriers:

- [`pthread_barrier_init`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_init)
- [`pthread_barrier_wait`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_wait)
- [`pthread_barrier_destroy`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_destroy)

Here's an example:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pthread_barrier_t bar;
pthread_t  th;

void* function(void*)
{  
    printf("Second thread before the barrier\n");
    pthread_barrier_wait(&bar);
    printf("Second thread after the barrier\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    printf("Main thread is beginning\n");
    pthread_barrier_init(&bar, NULL, 2);
    pthread_create(&th, NULL, function, NULL); 
    pthread_barrier_wait(&bar);
    printf("Main thread has passed the barrier\n");
    pthread_join(&th,NULL);
    pthread_barrier_destroy(&bar);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And writing "main thread has finished" in the main thread, when it has not finished, is misleading.

Comment: Is that use of `pthread_create()` really safe?  You should technically declare `function` as `void*function(void*)` to be compliant.

Comment: @Tomalak: technically speaking, it's impossible to write "main thread has finished" in the main thread before the main thread finishes...

Comment: @André: Huh? It's not impossible at all; the OP did it. What's impossible is doing it without lying to the person reading your program's output. :)

Comment: @André You could register a function with `atexit` and do it there, technically that should execute after main is complete...

Comment: That was not my question. You think I don't know about pthread_barrier_wait? I have been using it for a very long time. Read the last paragraph of the edited question and then answer.

Comment: @MetallicPriest: this site requires civility, so let me say this as civilly as I can. That was not the effing question you asked. I will not answer again, because that's not what you asked, and because of the poor way you responded. Bad manners will not get you very far on this site.

Answer (score 0):

A barrier is a [fairly standard synchronization primitive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barrier_%28computer_science%29).

In basic terms, upon entering a barrier each thread is blocked until all relevant threads have reached the barrier, and then all are released.

I know you're asking about C/C++, but take a look at Java's [`CyclicBarrier`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) as the concept is explained pretty well there.

Since you're asking about pthreads, take a look at [`pthread_barrier_init`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_init) et al.

**edit**

> But in this case, a thread seemingly dynamically inserts barriers in
>   the other threads. How?

It is hard to answer this without some kind of context (e.g. the paper that you're reading).

The excerpt that you quote gives an impression that this is a description of some low-level tool, that either inserts hooks that get executed on certain events (probably in the context of the threads in question), or indeed operates in kernel mode. Either way, it's little wonder it can do what it says it can.

It doesn't seem to me that anyone is talking about a user thread dynamically inserting barriers into another user thread.

Hope I'm not too far off in my guessing of the context.

Comment: I know about pthread_barrier_wait et all! I was asking about how to create a barrier at runtime. pthread_barrier_wait is used when you know where to place the barrier. But in this case, a thread seemingly dynamically inserts barriers in the other threads. How?

Comment: @MetallicPriest: I've updated the answer with my thoughts on this. If I'm off the mark, please provide some more context.

Answer (score -1):

Simple: use the pthread_barrier_wait pthread API call.

See the man page for the details: http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_barrier_wait

Comment: I know about pthread_barrier_wait, but my question was how to create a dynamic barrier.

Answer (score -1):

An OS thread barrier is nothing more than some state in memory. If you can share that state among threads (by properly initializing the threads) then the threads can use that barrier.

Essentially the main thread does:

```
CreateAllThreads(&barrier);
StartAllThreads();
EnterBarrier(&barrier);
```

All other threads do:

```
RuntimeInitialize();
EnterBarrier(&barrier);
```

The above is only a *very* rough pseudocode for illustrative purposes only.